# Incorrect syntax near '6'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I get the error on the first `6` in the code

This comes from dynamic sql and this is what it printed.

`...+ '' of '' ('+@Total+') AS TargetStatus...` : total is the 6

```
SELECT [Target Status] + '' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(255))+ ' of ' (6) AS TargetStatus, CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) / 6 AS [Count]
    FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,ISNULL(t2.AUD_CloseDate,GETDATE())), 101)) > CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,t2.AUD_TargetDate), 101))
            THEN 'Over Due: '
            ELSE 'On Time: ' END AS [Target Status]
            FROM #tmp1 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.Audit t2
            ON t1.AUD_ID = t2.AUD_ID
            WHERE t2.AUD_Deleted = 0
            AND t2.AUD_LeadAuditor IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] ('29'))
            AND t2.AUD_Year = 2011
            AND t2.AUD_ORGID IN (Select Org_ID From [database].[dbo].fx_Rights_ORGIDs( 120))
            AND AUD_Quarter IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] ('1')))
```

Don't know why it would say `near 6` its 2 brackets something?

Comment: What's that (6) in the first line there for?

Comment: It returns e.g. `1 of 6` ,`6` is the `@total`

Comment: So it should be inside the quotes.

Comment: something to do with the `(6) AS TargetStatus`

Comment: @MartinSmith : `('6')` gives same error

Comment: @TheUser ah, now I see what you're trying to do - answer below

Comment: Maybe 'of ' (6) should be 'of (6)'

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
[Target Status] + '' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(255))+ ' of  6' AS TargetStatus
```

The `6` should be part of the string.

Alternatively, use

```
[Target Status] + '' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(255))+ ' of  ' + CAST((6) AS NVARCHAR(15)) AS TargetStatus
```

Comment: `'...+ CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(255))  + '' of '' ('+@Total+') AS TargetStatus, CAST(COUNT(*)...' ` in dynamic sql so cant be part of string.

Comment: @TheUser Does my second variant deliver what you need? Actually, using `+ CAST(@Total AS NVARCHAR(15))` or similar?

Comment: no it still gives `Incorrect syntax near '('.`

Comment: @TheUser and you have the `+` before the opening parenthesis like in my proposal?

Comment: @FrankPI : `AS NVARCHAR(255)) + '' of '' + ('+ CAST(@Total AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+')`. I have it like that, remember its dynamic sql, I get same error just at AS

Answer (score 1):

Move the single quote to the right of the 6.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving that single quote, your `(6)` should be part of the string.

```
SELECT [Target Status] + '' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(255))+ ' of  (6)' AS TargetStatus, CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) / 6 AS [Count]
    FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,ISNULL(t2.AUD_CloseDate,GETDATE())), 101)) > CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,t2.AUD_TargetDate), 101))
            THEN 'Over Due: '
            ELSE 'On Time: ' END AS [Target Status]
            FROM #tmp1 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.Audit t2
            ON t1.AUD_ID = t2.AUD_ID
            WHERE t2.AUD_Deleted = 0
            AND t2.AUD_LeadAuditor IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] ('29'))
            AND t2.AUD_Year = 2011
            AND t2.AUD_ORGID IN (Select Org_ID From [database].[dbo].fx_Rights_ORGIDs( 120))
            AND AUD_Quarter IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] ('1')))
```

Comment: it comes from dynamic sql so not part of string. in tsql I have `'...+ CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(255))  + '' of '' ('+@Total+') AS TargetStatus, CAST(COUNT(*) ...'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at printing a staus and you are after a string like 'processed X of 6', then move the `(6)` in to the character string...

```
SELECT [Target Status] + '' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(255))+ ' of 6' AS TargetStatus, CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) / 6 AS [Count]
    FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,ISNULL(t2.AUD_CloseDate,GETDATE())), 101)) > CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,t2.AUD_TargetDate), 101))
            THEN 'Over Due: '
            ELSE 'On Time: ' END AS [Target Status]
            FROM #tmp1 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.Audit t2
            ON t1.AUD_ID = t2.AUD_ID
            WHERE t2.AUD_Deleted = 0
            AND t2.AUD_LeadAuditor IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] ('29'))
            AND t2.AUD_Year = 2011
            AND t2.AUD_ORGID IN (Select Org_ID From [database].[dbo].fx_Rights_ORGIDs( 120))
            AND AUD_Quarter IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] ('1')))
```

If you want '6' to become variable then you will have to look at using dynamic SQL.

Comment: in tsql I have it as `'...+ CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(255))  + '' of '' ('+@Total+') AS TargetStatus, CAST(COUNT(*) ...'`

Comment: You mean in dynamic SQL you have it as above... `+ '' of (' + @Total + ')''`...

Comment: yes, sorry! first time working with it.